# Meaning of 0xFF in SDL code

Tags: c++, sdl

```
 SDL_FillRect( screenSurface, NULL, SDL_MapRGB( screenSurface->format, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF ) )
```

What does 0xFF mean exactly?

Answer (score 2):

From the [man](https://wiki.libsdl.org/SDL_MapRGB):

> Use this function to map an RGB triple to an opaque pixel value for a
>   given pixel format.

```
Uint32 SDL_MapRGB(const SDL_PixelFormat* format,
                  Uint8                  r, 
                  Uint8                  g, 
                  Uint8                  b)
```

The r,g,b arguments of the function are the red green and blue component values that will be mapped to the provided opaque pixel value. This is based on the [RGB model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RGB_color_model). They are represented by an 8-bit unsigned integer, meaning their range are 0-255.

0xFF is a value in hexadecimal form.

0xFF is 255 in decimal.

RGB of 255,255,255 is the white color.